# XML serialization - bypass container class?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I am trying to serialize an object in a particular manner. The main class has a container class that holds some attributes, but really these attributes should be on the main class, from the point of view of the schema. Is there a way to bypass the container class and treat the properties on the container class as properties on the main class, for the purposes of serialization?

I am trying to create XML along the lines of:

```
<Main foo="3" bar="something">
  <Others>etc</Others>
</Main>
```

from this code:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("Main", Namespace = "")]
public class MainObject
{
    public HelperContainer { get; set; }

    public string Others { get; set; }
}

public class HelperContainer
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(AttributeName = "foo")]
    public int Foo { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(AttributeName = "bar")]
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Isn't cheaper/easier to create a class specific to your serialization requirement?

Comment: It's an existing class/data structure that is currently being used where the serialization isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try implementing IXmlSerializable on `MainObject` to be able to control what happens when calling serialize. For the read and write xml methods specify the fields to serialize.

Check out msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx

Something like:

```
public class MainObject : IXmlSerializable
{
    public HelperContainer { get; set; }

    public string Others { get; set; }

    public void WriteXml (XmlWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteString(Others);
        writer.WriteAttributeString("foo", HelperContainer.Foo);
        writer.WriteAttributeString("bar", HelperContainer.Bar);
    }

    public void ReadXml (XmlReader reader)
    {
        Others = reader.ReadString();
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: It is very painfull. I'd rather use Linq2Xml instead of using `IXmlSerializable`